# Where is my Area51 Discuss reputation going?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

Reputation awarded for up-votes on [Area51 Discuss](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) questions and answers only shows up in recent activity and is never added to the overall total.

Rep rewarded for commits, follows and example questions etc on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) work as expected.

In addition, there is often a disparity between rep counts on both sites if rep has been recently awarded. There seems to be a lag in syncing.

Where is this rep going? Should there be 2 rep counts one for discuss and one for main?

Comment: It's now added to your Area51 rep, you'd better edit the tag to be: status-completed :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I imagine that like the per-site-metas of the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, the reputation on the Area 51 Discussion is non-existent.

And to a degree, this can be seen as even more intentional and desired. The point of the Discussion is not to have a handful of "Meta Area 51" users who police the place and pass judgment on every proposal. It is meant for the followers and committers of each proposal to have some medium in order to communicate points. It is for those invested not merely in the Stack Exchange Network, but in the individual proposals themselves, to shuffle the ideas of proposals into real sites.

And so, the benefits of participating in Discussion is not that much about some global number that you can use as a reference point as you dance with other discussion threads. Instead, it's getting known with the future community for the proposal if it progresses, which helps build a stronger community when the site eventually reaches Beta and has its own per-site-meta. Of course, you still won't get reputation there, though. ♪

Comment: I had no idea rep was imaginary on some meta sites :/

Comment: @rjstelling Every Meta site outside of this one behaves the same way, it derives your reputation from the main Q&A site. Of course, like with Area 51, you can still track it using the envelope report. For example, I have 7428 reputation on Gaming Meta, which is hilariously higher than all of my non-Meta Stack Overflow account reputations combined.

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this 41 more times.

Comment: It's now added guys :)

Answer (score -1):

Checking my reputation last night, I noticed that my rep changed. Recalculating discuss rep and adding them to my Area51 rep, I realized that discuss rep now adds up!